# How can I find $\cos(\theta)$ with $\sin(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin^2x$ + $\sin^22x$ + $\sin^23x$ = 1, what does  $\cos^2x$ + $\cos^22x$ + $\cos^23x$ equal?

My attempted (and incorrect) solution:

- $\sin^2x$ + $\sin^22x$ + $\sin^23x$ = $\sin^26x$ = 1
- $\sin^2x = 1/6$
- $\sin x = 1/\sqrt{6}$
- $\sin x =$ opposite/hypotenuse
- Therefore, opp = 1, hyp = $\sqrt6$, adj = $\sqrt5$ (pythagoras theorum)
- $\cos x$ = adjacent/hypotenuse = $\sqrt5/\sqrt6$
- $\cos^2x$ = 5/6
- $\cos^2x + \cos^22x + \cos^23x = \cos^26x = 5/6 * 6 = 5$

I think I did something incorrectly right off the bat at step-2, and am hoping somebody will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, it was right off the bat at step $1$.

Comment: I somewhat knew it couldn't have been that easy

Comment: Recall that $\textrm{sin}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2 x = 1$.

Comment: Hint: The sum of our two expressions is equal to $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that
\begin{equation}
\textrm{sin}^2x + \textrm{sin}^2 2x + \textrm{sin}^2 3x = 1 \qquad (\textrm{Eq.} 1)
\end{equation}

Notice that 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{sin}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2 x = 1 \Rightarrow \textrm{sin}^2x = 1 - \textrm{cos}^2 x  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Substituting the identity in Equation (1):
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\underbrace{\textrm{sin}^2x}_{1-\textrm{cos}^2x} &  + \underbrace{\textrm{sin}^2 2x}_{1-\textrm{cos}^2 2x } + \underbrace{\textrm{sin}^2 3x}_{1-\textrm{cos}^2 3x} = 1 \\ \\ & \Rightarrow 1-\textrm{cos}^2x + 1-\textrm{cos}^2 2x + 1-\textrm{cos}^2 3x = 1 \\ & \Rightarrow 3 -\left( \textrm{cos}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2 2x + \textrm{cos}^2 3x \right) = 1 \\ & \Rightarrow 2 = \textrm{cos}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2 2x + \textrm{cos}^2 3x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Therefore: 
\begin{equation}
\textrm{cos}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2 2x + \textrm{cos}^2 3x = 2
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm curious if this type of thing becomes second nature eventually.

Comment: It is usually a lot of practice. For example $\textrm{sin}^2x + \textrm{cos}^2x = 1$ is present in many geometrical problems so after a while you'll learn it. Other identities are more difficult. My recommendation: when you are using trigonometric functions always keep a list (preferably a list made by you) of trigonometric identities. You can find one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities)

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^2x+\sin^22x+\sin^23x=1\implies(1-cos^2x)+ (1-\cos^22x) + (1-cos^23x)=1$

Rearranging terms we get $\cos^2x+\cos^22x+\cos^23x=2$